# Non-const lambda capture in const method

Tags: c++, lambda, this, c++17

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Blub {
public:
    int i = 0;
    std::function<void()> create() const {
        return [this]() {
            this->i = 100;
        };
    }
};

int main() {
    Blub blub = Blub();
    blub.create()();
    std::cout << blub.i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I know that `this` is captured as const inside the lambda, because the method is marked const.
Is there still a way, aside from removing the constness of the method, to archive that i can modify member variables inside the lambda function?

Adding `mutable` keyword is not working.

Comment: See if capturing `i` by reference works? I understand this is sample code, may not work in what your actual code looks like.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following **workaround**:

```cpp
class Blub {
public:
    int i = 0;
    std::function<void()> create() const {
        return [my_this=const_cast<Blub*>(this)]() {
            my_this->i = 100;
        };
    }
};
```

but it is misleading to change a data member in a function which is actually marked as `const` so I wouldn't suggest designing your class in that way.

Check it out [live](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:24,endLineNumber:13,positionColumn:24,positionLineNumber:13,selectionStartColumn:24,selectionStartLineNumber:13,startColumn:24,startLineNumber:13),source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cfunctional%3E%0A%0Aclass+Blub+%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++int+i+%3D+0%3B%0A++++std::function%3Cvoid()%3E+create()+const+%7B%0A++++++++return+%5Bmy%3Dconst_cast%3CBlub*%3E+(this)%5D()+%7B+my-%3Ei+%3D+100%3B+%7D%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++Blub+blub+%3D+Blub()%3B%0A++++blub.create()()%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+blub.i+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:49.85494633014216,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%232+with+x86-64+gcc+9.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).

**N.B.** It is worth to mention that `const_cast` is safe to use only if it's used for casting a variable that was originally non-`const`. If the variable is originally `const`, using `const_cast` could result in Undefined Behavior. So, in the following code (which the OP provided):

```cpp
int main() {
    Blub blub = Blub();
    blub.create()();
    std::cout << blub.i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

it is safe to use `const_cast` because object is originally made non-`const`. However, if we make it `const` like in the following code:

```cpp
int main() {
    const Blub blub = Blub();
    blub.create()();
    std::cout << blub.i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

it will result in an Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Important note: if you use `const_cast` to discard constness of something which is actually const, UB may occur (such as, optimization using old state of object because it thinks it can't change).

Comment: @hyde Tnx for pointing this out but I thought that `const_cast` could lead to UB only if the object is originally const and `this` is not originally const. It is just made const within this function. Maybe I got this wrong. What do you think about my thoughts?

Comment: In the question code it should be ok, sure. But that's obviously not the real code OP is working on. It might, or it might not be ok there.

Comment: @hyde I got your point... Anyway, I will add a sidenote to my answer once I am close to my laptop

Comment: `const Blub b; b.create()(); std::cout << b.i;` Are you telling me this isn't undefined behaviour?

Comment: @JohnIlacqua this IS undefined behavior because object is originally made `const`. I explained that in my answer, didn't I?

Comment: "this is originally non-const variable (this should be obvious since we are using reference to this everytime we modify our class members, and we do that first time in the constructor)" is unclear/doesn't make sense. There's no constructor call in any code in your answer, and nothing about a constructor has anything to do with whether or not the object is declared as `const`. I think this is a bad answer, because it is suggesting a class design that lends itself very easily to a use case that results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: @JohnIlacqua part of the answer marked with **N.B.** is a general explanation and is not strictly applied to the code provided and, indeed, there is a constructor call in the code OP has provided. Don't you see that?

Comment: You said "in the code I wrote above", so I assumed you were talking about the code written by you that is above that statement, rather than code that exists in the question written by someone else. And the constructor call is still irrelevant to the `const`ness.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207240/discussion-between-nutcracker-and-john-ilacqua).

Answer (score 3):

You can declare the member variable `i` as `mutable`, so that it could change even if the object is declared as `const`:

```
class Blub {
public:
    mutable int i = 0;
//  ^^^^^^^
    std::function<void()> create() const {
        return [this]() {
            this->i = 100;
        };
    }
};
```

Live [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/asEXfliy8Gz3dqrY).